# How to avoid a equation tag enumerate and then continue with automatically enumeration?

Tags: equations

My question is the next one: I have two special cases of the same equation, I need to change enumerate manually with a `\tag{}` but then, I need that the mark of equations follows the previous automatically enumerate.
To illustrate my point follow the next example:

```
\begin{equation} a+b=c \end{equation}
```

Who is referenced with a (1.1) mark.

Then I have the special cases of the equation:

1.

```
\begin{equation} u(c,n)=log(C_{t})-log(n_{t}) \tag(1.2.1) \end{equation}
```

2. 

```
\begin{equation} u(c,n)=C_{t}-n_{t} \tag(1.2.2) \end{equation}
```

But in the next equation I used:

```
\begin{equation} a+b=2x+g \end{equation}
```

It was referenced with (1.2) mark and I need that follows the previous enumeration, therefore, the correct number should be (1.3).

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: `\stepcounter{equation}`

Comment: It worked perfect, thank you David

Comment: You might use the `subequations` environment.

Answer (score 2):

Using an explicit tag and then stepping the counter manual is not recommended, because the numbering could change and so the tag with it.

The `amsmath` package provides `subequations` for this purpose. Unfortunately, the subnumbering with letters is hardwired, but it's not difficult to change it as desired.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\appto\subequations{%
  \renewcommand{\theequation}{\theparentequation.\arabic{equation}}%
}


\begin{document}

\section{Title}

One equation with its number
\begin{equation}\label{A}
x^2+y^2=z^2
\end{equation}
and some text after it.

\begin{subequations}\label{B}
Now we state an equation
\begin{equation}\label{B1}
u(c,n)=\log(C_{t})-\log(n_{t})
\end{equation}
and next a variant thereof
\begin{equation}\label{B2}
u(c,n)=C_{t}-n_{t}
\end{equation}
with some text after them.
\end{subequations}

One equation with its number
\begin{equation}\label{C}
x^2+y^2=z^2
\end{equation}
and some text after it.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note, in passing, that `\log` should be used, not `log`.

The labels I have used can be whatever you wish, of course. I added a label also after `\begin{subequations}`, so you can refer to equation 1.2 in the text, if you need to.